# c# Reading a text file using OpenFileDialog and then make the average

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I need to make this :

Make a Windows program to read numbers from a file with a box 
OpenFileDialog dialog. The program must find the average of the numbers and 
show it to display a text box.

I only open the file and i show it in the textbox but, i don't know how i can calculate the average from the file, i tried put the file content into array and then make the operation but don't works.

```
private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "File text(*.txt)|*.txt|File jgp (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string cad = sr.ReadToEnd();

        txt1.Text = cad;

        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}

private void Average_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string res = txt1.Text;            
    mitja.Text = res;
}
```

Comment: How is the file made up?

Comment: The file have only Numbers

Comment: But how are the numbers seperated?

Comment: One per line? Something else? (Consider doing this not in the UI thread, too...)

Comment: Why are you adding images to the file filter?

Comment: David Pilkington it is only a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cad.Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a)).Average(a => a);
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct (assuming whole numbers), however the OP will need to consider what they want to happen if one of the "numbers" doesn't parse. Fail? Ignore it?

Comment: @Liath Agreed, I am assuming ideal input.

Comment: ideal for the example - just wanted the OP to consider it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `var nums = cad.Split(" ")` and `Integer.Parse(nums[0])`